# OCP 7 II regular expression

Tags: java, regex

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Regex2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("ab34ef");
        boolean b = false;
        while ( m.find()) {
            System.out.print(m.start() + m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Why this code produce output: 01234456

Comment: If you use `println`, it would be more clear for you to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@vks is right:
If you are using `\\d*` it works on each characters:

```
Index: char = matching:
    0: 'a'  = "" because no integer
    1: 'b'  = "" because no integer
    2: '3'  = "34" because there is two integer between index [2-3]
       '4'    is not checked because the index has been incremented in previous check.
    4: 'e'  = ""
    5: 'f'  = "" because no integer
    6: ''   = "" IDK
```

It produce 0, "", 1, "", 2, "34", 4, "", 5, "", 6, "" = **01234456** (that's why you got it).

If you use `\\d+` only the groups with one or more integer will match.

Answer (score 1):

```
\d* means integer 0 or more times.So an empty string between a and b ,before a ...those are also

matched.Use `\d+` to get correct result.
```

See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fG5pZ8/25

Answer (score 0):

Because `\\d*` indicates zero or more digits.

As,

[image]